# One app -> multiple languages

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

So I have my app in the App Store. I have the app in my language(Norwegian), and I have the same app in English, but right now there are two different apps in the App Store. The apps are 100% the same, but I have made it as two different apps in the App Store and iTunes Connect because they are different languages. Is it possible that I only have it as one app in iTunes Connect? Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that I only have it as one app in iTunes Connect?

Yes. Abandon one of the apps (remove it from the store) and [localize](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/) the other app for Norwegian and English.

Comment: How exactly? Is there any tutorials or something because I have no idea..

Comment: Click the link. Read. Click links in that page. Learn. Do.

Comment: Should I keep the oldest app from iTunes Connect(Norwegian version) or the English one? And what about the display name in App Store? How do I edit that to be Norwegian in the Norwegian version, and English in the English version?

Comment: I don’t see that it matters which one you keep. You’ll annoy some users either way.  Of course it would have been better never to have doubled the app in the first place.